# onBeforeAction, wrong redirect

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My routes file:

```
Router.map ->
    @route 'mainPage', path: '/'
    @route 'login', 
        path:'/admin/login'
        onBeforeAction: ->
            @redirect '/' if Meteor.user()
            @next()

class @AdminController extends RouteController
    layoutTemplate: 'AdminHead'
    onBeforeAction: ->
        @redirect 'login' unless Meteor.user()
        @next()

Router.route 'dashboard', 
        controller: 'AdminController'
        path: '/admin'
Router.route 'addArticle', 
        controller: 'AdminController'
        path: '/admin/addArticle'
```

It's should not redirect to login page after authorization, but it's redirects. What i do wrong?

Comment: Do you have waitOn function somewhere? It most likely doesn't wait for Meteor.user() to be created

Comment: There is no waitOn function.

Comment: Then make one, and put subscriptions in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect
if `Meteor.user()` or `Meteor.loggingIn()`

This way it wont redirect to the login page if the user is still logging in.

[Meteor.logginIn()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loggingin)